# How do I count 2 uniques in excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

How do I program the logic for Buyer Status in Column C?

- Repeat buyers are

  1. Customer IDs with multiple Dates
- One time buyers are

  1. Customer IDs with unique dates

[image: Excel]

Comment: Did either of the below answers solve the issue? If so, can you please mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,"<>" & A2),"Repeat Buyer","One Time Buyer")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Scott, Just tried this and it worked - although it crashed my excel. I have 200,000 records. Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: VBA, using arrays to do the whole at once. @kadvani1

Comment: How do I do it in VBA? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a PivotTable out of your data, and put ID in it twice...once as a ROW Field, and once as a VALUES field, and change the aggregation from SUM to COUNT:

[image]

Click the dropdown arrow on the ID field of the PivotTable, and select More Sort Options...

[image]

...then change the dropdown so it says 'Count of CustomerID' and push OK:

[image]

...and then you're done. Anyone with a Count of 1 at the top is a one-time buyer. Anyone else is a Repeat Buyer.

[image]